# LTSpice: How can I specify a constant-dependent delay?

Tags: ltspice, spice, pspice

I am defining a voltage source that depends on the voltage at another point in the circuit.

B1 N1 0 V = if ({dly}> 0, delay (V (In), 2m), V (In))

This works perfectly! If I do dly> 0, B1 has a 2 ms delay. However, I want to make the delay dependent on dly. So, I try this.

.params dly = 2m
B1 N1 0 V = if ({dly}> 0, delay (V (In), {dly}), V (In))

So, I get an error message. "A constant delay must be specified as positive definite".

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my complete subckt.

```
.subckt Ultrasound In Out Ref 
.params Ind = 0.04*(40/{f}) Cap = 2/({Ind}*(2*pi*{f}*1000)**2)  Res = .1e6
.params Amp = 10*({Res}**-0.5)
.params dly=0 dly2 = if(dly>0,dly,1)
* I also tested it as follows. Did not work.
*.params dly=0 dly2 = if(dly,dly,1)

* Model
B1 N1 N3 V=Amp*if(dly>0,delay(V(In,Ref),dly2),V(In,Ref))

C1 N1 N2 {Cap}
L1 N2 Out {Ind}
C2 Out N3 {Cap}
R1 Out N3 {Res}

* Noise
B2 N3 0 V=30e-3*white(1e6*time)

B3 Ref N4 V=V(N3,0)
R2 N4 0 0.1

.ends
```

Here is the asy file, where dly is defined.

```
Version 4
SymbolType CELL
LINE Normal 48 112 48 80
LINE Normal 96 32 64 32
LINE Normal 32 32 0 32
RECTANGLE Normal 32 -16 64 80
SYMATTR Value Ultrasound
SYMATTR Prefix X
SYMATTR ModelFile Ultrasound.cir
SYMATTR SpiceLine f=40 dly=0
SYMATTR Description 
PIN 0 32 BOTTOM 8
PINATTR PinName In
PINATTR SpiceOrder 1
PIN 96 32 BOTTOM 8
PINATTR PinName Out
PINATTR SpiceOrder 2
PIN 48 112 RIGHT 18
PINATTR PinName Ref
PINATTR SpiceOrder 3
```

Comment: I can't duplicate your issue.  Can you edit your question to include either the SPICE netlist or `.asc` file text pasted into a code-block?

Comment: Could you use a transmission line to model the delay?

Answer (score 2):

The delay can't be zero valued, so when `dly > 0` it works just fine. But the whole `if()` expression needs to be parsed prior to simulation, and when `dly = 0`, the `delay()` function is parsed and `dly` is replaced by its evaluated number, which is zero, and which gives a rightful error.

To solve this, make a second variable and replace `dly` inside the behavioural source:

```
.param dly=0 dly2=if(dly, dly, 1)
V=if(dly, delay(V(in), dly2), V(in))
```

This way, when `dly == 0`, `dly2` will evaluate to something greater than 0. That branch will not be executed, but the evaluation will not result in an error.

---

Given the way the discussion went in the comments I don't know whether my English is to blame or you don't read my answer, but I'll give it another try.

Your original expression had a conditional, `if()`, and a `delay()`. The way the parser works is it first reads the whole expression and tries to make sense of it. The `delay()` function, as you had it written, was a function of `dly` which could be set to zero. Even if the condition would result in the other branch being executed, the parser still sees the whole expression and the fact that `dly` evaluates to zero in a `delay()` function. And since `delay()` needs an argument for delay that is positive definite, the parser finds this an error and aborts the simulation.

The solution that I proposed was to use a proxy for `dly`, named `dly2`, which has its own conditional to determine whether `dly` is positive definite or not and, if it is, to use its value, otherwise to use *some other* value -- it doesn't matter what value as long as it evaluates to a positive definite one. This way, when `dly == 0`, the parser finds the `delay()` function to have an argument that doesn't result in an error. The reason I chose `1`, or the reason why your choice, `1e6`, worked just as well, was because when `dly2` evaluates to that, `dly == 0`, and the other branch of the `if()` is executed.

```
if( dly > 0)
    delay()
else       // <-- this branch is executed when dly == 0
    normal
```

Remember, `dly2` is there to avoid a zero-valued delay, that's all. It doesn't matter if it's `1n`, or `1meg`, when `dly == 0` it makes `dly2 > 0` and `delay()` is not the one that is executed. So it has nothing to do with `.asy`, or `.param` statments, it's just a trick to get around the zero delay problem. That's all.

Comment: I just realized it should be `dly2=if(dly>0, ...)`, otherwise the default boolean check is true for `>=0.5`.

Comment: I am trying to model an ultrasound sensor. The same sensor can be used as a receiver or as an emitter. So, in my circuit, there are two instances of the same component. One is used as an emitter and the other is used as a receiver. So, one must have dly = 0 and the other must have dly = 1m. dly simulates the time it takes the ultrasound to reach the receiver. When I set dly = 0 in one instance, this also changes dly = 0 in the other instance. :-( It looks like I will have to create a sensor that it can only be used as a transmitter and another that can only be used as a receiver.

Comment: @JAlexFrança So then my suggestion doesn't work?

Comment: Did not work! I had already tried something like that. I will try to put the complete subckt here.

Comment: I edited my question and inserted my complete subckt.

Comment: @JAlexFrança You haven't done what I said. You defined `dly2` as dependent of `dly`, but you didn't define `dly` anywhere. You also wrote `dly/1000`, why? Then you made a function that's useless because it's only called once (though it doesn't hurt, either). And the curly braces are not needed in `.param` statements or `.func` definitions, or even in `BV` and `BI` behavioural sources; they just obscure things here. Read more carefully what I did. Replace your `.param dly2` line with my `.param` line, the `.func` can be removed, replace `V=` in your `B1` with my line (but with `V(in,Ref)` ...

Comment: ... and `Amp*` in front. It should look like this now: `V=Amp*if(dly, delay(V(in,ref), dly2), V(in,ref))`. There's also no need for `B3` since `B2` is doing just that.

Comment: The dly parameter is defined in the asf file. I edited my question to include this file. It must be defined for each component instance. I will test what you suggested next.

Comment: @JAlexFrança Yes, but your `.func` uses `MyDly(dly2)`, not `MyDly(dly)`. `dly2` is meant to be a proxy for `dly`, not to be used directly. That's why I said look again, carefully, at what I did.

Comment: I had already tested it both ways. Here is the version I just tested. It still didn't work! Do I make a mistake in the asf file? I think the problem is there.

Comment: .subckt Ultrasound In Out Ref 
.params Ind = 0.04*(40/{f}) Cap = 2/({Ind}*(2*pi*{f}*1000)**2)  Res = .1e6
.params Amp = 10*({Res}**-0.5)
.params dly2 = if(dly>0,dly/1000,0)

B1 N1 N3 V=Amp*if(dly>0,delay(V(In,Ref),dly2),V(In,Ref))

Comment: @JAlexFrança Is that how my conditional looks like? Is that what my explanation says? Look again. My line says if `dly` is defined then use `dly` -- **not** `dly/1000` --, else use `1` -- **not** `0`. I also said to get rid of the unnecessary curly braces, but it looks like it's a bad reflex you want to have. And there's no `.asf` file, maybe you meant `.asc`, which is the schematic, itself, or `.asy`, which is the symbol. Not lastly, I have no idea what circuit you're trying to build, but the `Ref` pin has `0.1` resistance and the output comes out noise, only, no matter what input.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I meant asy file. But ... dly is user defined. It can be 0, 1, 2, 3m or any other user-defined value greater than zero. So, I can't do ".param dly = 0 dly2 = if (dly, dly, 1)". dly and dly2 cannot be defined on the same line. dly must be defined externally to the subckt, in the asy file. Also, in my asc file, there are two instances of the component. So, dly is defined twice. I think this is the source of the problem.

Comment: @JAlexFrança Instead of making up your own explanations, why not try what I said? The two parameters can be defined on the same line, inside the subcircuit. That serves as a default value for them. If you don't define them inside the subcircuit and forget to pass it on in the symbol, afterwards, the simulation will abort with an error because there is no parameter defined. `dly` in `.param` is the definition, `dly` in the `.asy` is the usage. If you had tried this, you would have found out you were wrong. So please stop making up (wrong) explanations and try what is said, as it's said.

Comment: I edited my question again. See if the subckt is in accordance with what you have suggested.

Comment: @JAlexFrança Is it still complaining about a zero delay? Because, as I said, I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish with such a circuit. That's up to you to know. Otherwise, as it is, [it's working for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwdIO.png). Saying "it's not working" is not enough. What is it that's not working?

Comment: With this subckt, I don't get any error messages and the simulation is run. However, in this case, the signal has no delay. Even if I set dly = 0.4 (via the .asy file), there is no delay. This looks like (always) "B1 N1 N3 V = Amp * V (In, Ref)".

Comment: @JAlexFrança My first comment was about the `if()` statement, but the condition applies in general. Not specifying `x` in `dly>x` results in the check being `dly>=0.5`. The same goes for the behavioural source: modify the condition to be `dly>0`, instead of just `dly`, and it will work.

Comment: I edited the subckt again as you suggested. Look up there. Now it worked! :-) However, I have no idea why it worked. It doesn't make any sense to me. It works even if I do "dly2 = if (dly> 0, dly, 1E6)". Can you tell me where I can read more about the .params directive and .asy files to try to understand the solution? Thank you very much for your help and patience!

Comment: @JAlexFrança I don't know what in my original answer you didn't understand, but I modified my answer with another explanation. I don't know what to say more than this.